# Python не видит изменений в коде

Tags: python, ubuntu, telegram-bot, telegram, python-telegram-bot

Я только начал изучать python и пытаюсь создать бота для Telegram с помощью python-telegram-bot.

Но я столкнулся с проблемой, мой бот не реагирует на изменения, которые я делаю в коде. Чтобы обновить изменения, мне нужно каждый раз перезагружать python.

Пользуюсь на Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, python 3.10.4, visual studio code

Comment: «нужно каждый раз перезагружать python» — почему вы считаете это проблемой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Это не проблема. Так устроен интерпретатор Python.**

Сначала он переводится в байт код, затем интерпретируется. Поэтому и не видит изменения, которые Вы вводите в реальном времени.

В любом случае, есть такие инструменты, но они мне неизвестны.

Comment: Есть такие инструменты, только не автоматически, т.к. в общем случае это корректно сделать нельзя (например, что делать с существующим состоянием переменных, стека вызовов и т.д), тут нужно чтоб приложение само было к этому готово и делало это в момент, когда оно готово. Инструмент для этого выгрузик/перезагрузка модулей. Из практических примеров такое умеет делать в режиме разработки например django и flask.